Allowing unspecified JSON fields to turn into Option.None when deserializing with FSharp.SystemTextJson
Reading the docs of FSharp.SystemTextJson it makes me think that allowing unspecified JSON fields to turn into None is possible:

By default, FSharp.SystemTextJson throws an exception when the
following conditions are met:

it is deserializing a record or a union;
a field's JSON value is null or the field is unspecified;
that field's type isn't an explicitly nullable F# type (like option, voption and Skippable)


But using a slightly modified code from the example, and leveraging on the statement of the third condition:
F# script -> Test.fsx:
#r "nuget: FSharp.SystemTextJson"

open System.Text.Json
open System.Text.Json.Serialization

type Point() =
    member val X = 0. with get, set
    member val Y = 0. with get, set

type Rectangle =
    { BottomLeft: Point option // <-- Marked as optional
      TopRight: Point }

let fsoptions =
    JsonFSharpOptions()
      .WithAllowNullFields(true) //in my tests it doesn't matter if it is true or false 

let options = fsoptions.ToJsonSerializerOptions()
options.PropertyNamingPolicy <- JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase //I need to allow camel case

//the BottomLeft field is missing from the JSON, the deserializer should turn that into None
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rectangle>("""{"topRight":{"x":1,"y":2}}""", options)

Instead I get an exception:

System.Text.Json.JsonException: Missing field for record type
FSI_0045+Rectangle: bottomLeft    at
System.Text.Json.Serialization.Helpers.failf@12.Invoke(String x)    at
System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonRecordConverter1.ReadRestOfObject(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Boolean skipFirstRead) in /home/runner/work/FSharp.SystemTextJson/FSharp.SystemTextJson/src/FSharp.SystemTextJson/Record.fs:line 203    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonRecordConverter1.Read(Utf8JsonReader&
reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) in
/home/runner/work/FSharp.SystemTextJson/FSharp.SystemTextJson/src/FSharp.SystemTextJson/Record.fs:line
180

Am I missing something? I know that this kind of operation is possible using since I'm migrating from NewtonSoft.Json + FSharpLu.Json to System.Text.Json + FSharp.SystemTextJson, and the former has allowed me to do this with no problems.
I first ran into the issue with my own types, but I figured using the examples provided by the library more convenient.
I've been reading the docs of the library, I can't find any other setting to toggle to allow this behavior.

I get the same error when I use the unaltered example from FSharp.SystemTextJson, so this looks like a bug in that package.

@BrianBerns thanks so much for testing. I think it's the first time for the me that the bug might actually not be in my code. I'll submit an issue to the github repository.

Brief exchange with the library author:

What the doc says is that in the case where the field's type is a class
(not an option), then AllowNullFields will allow it to be null. If you
want to allow None to represent a missing field, then what you need
is:
.WithSkippableOptionFields(SkippableOptionFields.Always)
Or if you want both absence and null to be deserialized as None:
.WithSkippableOptionFields(SkippableOptionFields.Always, deserializeNullAsNone = true)

And sure enough it is now working. The config should look like this:
let options =
    JsonFSharpOptions()
        .WithSkippableOptionFields(SkippableOptionFields.Always, deserializeNullAsNone = true)

